# Wrong NPM Package Version, Mocha Unknown Option --exit

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I'm trying to run the following command, and it's giving me the following error.

```
$ mocha --exit
error: unknown option `--exit'
```

When I run the following I get.

```
$ mocha --version
2.5.3
```

So that makes me think my version is wrong. But then when trying to list it I get this.

```
$ npm list mocha
MyApp@0.0.0 .../Code
└── mocha@4.0.1
```

So that makes me think it's running the latest version.

The last strange thing is running the following.

```
$ mocha -h

    ...
    --no-exit                               require a clean shutdown of the event loop: mocha will not call process.exit
    ...
    --use_strict                            enforce strict mode
    --watch-extensions <ext>,...            additional extensions to monitor with --watch
    --delay                                 wait for async suite definition
```

As you can see there is a `--no-exit` option but no `--exit` option. What's strange is when looking at the [code](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v4.0.1/bin/_mocha#L97) there is an option for `--exit`. Also in the code there are 3 more options at the [end](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v4.0.1/bin/_mocha#L115) that don't appear in my version.

Any ideas what is going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was because I had Mocha installed globally. I ran `npm ls -g --depth=0` to get all my global packages, but Mocha wasn't displaying.

Turns out I had Mocha installed globally **before** I started using NVM.

In order to fix this I had to disable NVM, remove Mocha from my old Node setup and then re-enable NVM then restart my terminal. This fixed the issue.

Comment: Save my day. Thanks @charlie